# Git server-side hook: How to get remote URL from the server side

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, githooks

I have my own git server, and I am using git hooks (server side) to setup a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. Currently I have an update hook doing a validation check, and a post-receive hook CURLing my Jenkins URL to trigger a build. I need to pass the remote URL of the repository to my Jenkins build, however I cannot find a way to receive the remote URL on the server side. I'd like to avoid a client-side hook, as people will be creating new repositories all the time, and I'd prefer to avoid having to enforce the hooks that they have on their end.

Is there any way to do this? Preferably he cleanest approach possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The remote url could be like `https://foo/bar.git`. In the git hooks it should be possible to get the absolute path to the hosted repository by `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, which may return `/opt/repositories/bar.git`. Join the fixed part `http://foo/` and the volatile part `bar.git` to form the url and then pass it to the pipeline. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something along the lines of this, but was missing that rev-parse --show-toplevel. Thanks!